# Php-Mysql-smarty getting datas from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a problem. I can't solve it. I am not good in PHP-MySQL.

I have three tables.

First Table : linkss    --> rows: linkid,link,orderlink

Second Table: sublinkss1 --> rows: sublink1id,sublink1,ordersublink1,link,linkid

Third table : sublinkss2 --> rows: sublink2id,sublink2,ordersublink2,sublink1,sublink1id

```
 $get_data=mysql_query("select linkss.link, sublinkss1.sublink1, sublinkss2.sublink2 from linkss,sublinkss1, sublinkss2 where sublinkss1.linkid=linkss.linkid and sublinkss2.sublink1id=sublinkss1.sublink1id order by orderlink, ordersublink1, ordersublink2");
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {
    $data[$row["link"]][$row["sublink1"]][$row["sublink2"]]=array($row["link"],$row["sublink1"],$row["sublink2"]);        
    }          
    $smarty = new Smarty();        
    $smarty->assign('data',$data);
```

and tpl file is this

```
<ul>
{foreach key=link from=$data item=linkss}
<li><a href="#">{$link}</a>
<ul>
{foreach key=sublink1 item=sublinkss1 from=$linkss }
<li><a href="#">
{$sublink1}
</a>

<ul>
{foreach key=sublink2 item=sublinkss2 from=$sublinkss1 }
<li><a href="#">
{$sublink2}
</a>

</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>

</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>

</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

For example some datas are stored in the database and I want output like this

```
<ul>
<li>Home Page
<ul><li>Projects</li></ul>
</li>
<li>About Us
<ul><li>History</li></ul>
<ul><li>Products
<ul><li>Product1</li></ul>
<ul><li>Product2</li></ul>
<ul><li>Product3</li></ul>
</li></ul>
</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

But these codes are not working properly. I tried to use inner join and left join but I couldn't handle it. Could you help me please.

Comment: Where is the fault? The result of SQL is OK? The html generated by smarty?

Comment: if any item is empty, it returns array of $data null . for example it can not print the output which is above.

Comment: So do you want an array with similar items: array("name" => "MenuName1", "submenu" => array( array("name"=>"SubMenu1", "submenu"=>array(...)), array("name"=>"SubMenu2", "submenu"=>array(...)) ). Right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need similar SQL-query as you wrote in your question. In this case you'll get similar lines:

```
link1,sublink1,subsublink1
link1,sublink1,subsublink2
link1,sublink1,subsublink3
link1,sublink2,subsublink4
link1,sublink2,subsublink5
link1,sublink2,subsublink6
...
link2,sublink3,subsublink7
...
```

You can rearrange this result to smarty:

```
current_link = ""; current_sublink = "";
desired_array = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $desired_array[$r["link"]]["sublinks"][$r["sublink1"]][] = $r["sublink2"]; 
}
```

If I wrote it correct your result will convert into array like this:

```
array(
    "link1" => array(
         "sublinks" => array(
              "sublink1" => array("subsublink1","subsublink2",...),
              "sublink2" => array("subsublink3","susbulink4",...),
              ...
         )
    ),
    "link2" => array(
         // same as link1
    )
)
```

If you've link which doesn't have sublink you'll need `FROM link LEFT JOIN sublink1 ON ... LEFT JOIN sublink2 ON...` instead of `FROM link,sublink1,sublink2` and you'll need a little modification in PHP-code.

In smarty: you'll need nested `foreach`:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$desired_array key=link item=link_item}
   <li>{$link}
       <ul>
       {foreach from=$link_item["sublinks"] key=sublink1 item=sublink_item}
          <li>{$sublink1}
          <ul>
          {foreach from=$sublink item=sublink_item2}
             <li>{$sublink_item2}</li>
          {/foreach}
          </ul></li>
       {/foreach}
       </ul>
   </il>
 {/foreach}
```

Maybe these codes aren't perfect but I think it's a good starting point (you can include check that count of sublink array isn't zero, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ... I learned lot... I will change the tables.. I found this to make a menu ... it looks good... and maybe this will run faster than mine... here is http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/web-database-design/dynamic-multilevel-css-menu-php-mysql/